# How to cancel an outgoing email send via SMTP server?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, smtp

I am using https://github.com/kailoa/iphone-smtp  code for sending mail via smtp server. I am able to send mail properly. But i have a requirement that when user has pressed a button the mail should not be send. Is there any way through which we can stop sending mail (if the request has already been made).

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can't withdraw an email without the ability to delete the recipients copy of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cant say im any familiar with this.
You cant withdraw an email that has already been sent, that i am pretty sure of.

But what you can do, is setup some timed delay. i.e of 10 seconds before its shipped to the SMTP handler.

Flow: 
1) Write the Email
2) Press send
3) Put in some sort of QUEUE (Array of message objects?) 
4) Setup some timer that would trigger after 10 seconds to loop trough the array and send the messages.

If the user presses "Cancel" or "Delete" or something on the message before the timer is running. then delete the object from the array. and it wont send the message :)

Hope this helps!